# How do I show left double quotes inside a button?

Tags: html, css

This is what I have tried.

```css
body{
  background: lightblue;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}
span {  
  quotes: "“" "”" "‘" "’";
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
span::before {
    content: open-quote;
    font-size: 35px;
    vertical-align: -0.6rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 offset-sm-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
          <button class="btn btn-primary mt-2">
            <span/> New Quote
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

No matter what I change I'm not able to remove that bottom padding.

Also, I am not able to get that exact look as per the image. Does the image have a different font-family?

My expected output is as shown below.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Try copy and pasting this https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/punctuation/left-double-quotation-mark/

Comment: Run your code snippet here and Inspect the button element `<button class="btn btn-primary mt-2">` — you'l find there's not much padding and it's specified in "rem" units `padding: .375rem .75rem;` which comes from the `.btn` class in "_buttons.scss" from bootstrap. You could override that, but (again) there's very little padding.  It's the `line-height` as Temani Afif says, being set to 1.5 in the same CSS rule that's creating most of that space.

Comment: @S.Ramjit — Ashik is not having any trouble using the Unicode _Left Double Quotation Mark_. It is already specified in `quotes: "“" "”" "‘" "’";` Copying from that page wouldn't change anything. The quotes _look_ different because, as Ashik wonders, they are using a different `font-family`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so many trials, finally got it.

Thank you everyone for your help.

```css
body {
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

span {
  quotes: "“" "”" "‘" "’";  
  font-family: sans-seif;
}

span::before {
  content: open-quote;
  font-size: 49px;
  vertical-align: -1.2rem;
  line-height: 0.4;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

button{
  padding: 0px;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 0px 8px 0px 6px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 offset-sm-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
          <button class="mt-2">
            <span/>New Quote
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: FWIW, on iOS Safari it looks nothing like that image in your question. If you want such pixel perfect graphics, you’ll have to use an image.

Comment: @deceze I'm not sure why it looks different in your device. But I am happy with the output in this solution. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

reduce the line-height:

```css
body {
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

span {
  quotes: "“" "”" "‘" "’";
  font-family: sans-seif;
}

span::before {
  content: open-quote;
  font-size: 35px;
  vertical-align: -0.7rem;
  line-height: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 offset-sm-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
          <button class="btn btn-primary mt-2">
            <span/> New Quote
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The quotes look different. Could you please change it. Also there is so much padding inside the button.

Comment: @AshikPaul well, I gave you the main trick. Now it's up to you to adjust the value to get the result you need (play with line-height, font-size, vertical-align, font-family, etc)